# JTextPane multi-line to single-line conversion with HTML

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I have a piece in my code that formats a string, appends html/css tags and then adds the text to a JTextPane. I create the textPane in some panel's constructor with the following:

```
    public PnlSmartCommands(ServerLogFormatter formatter, ServerCommandsComponent container){
    setLayout( new java.awt.BorderLayout() );
    this.container = container;
    txtServerCommands = new JTextPane();
    txtServerCommands.setContentType("text/html");
    scpServerCommands = new JScrollPane( );
    this.formatter = formatter;
    scpServerCommands.setViewportView( txtServerCommands );
    scpServerCommands.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(16);
    scpServerCommands.getHorizontalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(50);
    add( scpServerCommands, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER );
    txtServerCommands.setEditable(false);
    loadRules(txtServerCommands);
```

and I add text to the pane with a formatting function that takes all previous requests from an ArrayList, deletes all found HTML tags, formats it and then adds new HTML and BODY tags, and then use .setText(String arg0) to set the text to a JTextPane.

```
    public String formatMemoryString(){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("<html>");
    sb.append("<body>");
    for(int i=0;i<logMemoryHolder.size(); i++){
        sb.append(logMemoryHolder.get(i));
        if(!(i==logMemoryHolder.size())){
            sb.append("<br>");
        }
    }
    sb.append("</body>");
    sb.append("</html>");
    return sb.toString();
```

Now here's the problem - the response is always fit into the box over multiple lines, not on a single line. While this is actually good, I need to add functionality to span it over a single line. ! https://i.stack.imgur.com/zy4yC.jpg - this is what it looks like currently. I would like to add a checkbox that formats the value as a single line, or allows the textPane to do so. Any idea how I go about doing that? The HTML that I put into the pane is as follows : http://www.upload.ee/files/3501071/testHtml.html.html
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Okay, I seem to have solved my own problem by using HTML properties.

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/163188).